# How to assign userId on serenity MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I want to save CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy field on every table. Is there base resulution on serenity? 
I am getting error below when i set fld field:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Serenity.Data.Int32Field'

```
    private static MyRow.RowFields fld { get { return MyRow.Fields; } }           
    protected override void SetInternalFields()
            {

                int userId = ((UserDefinition)Authorization.UserDefinition).UserId;
                fld.LastModifiedBy = userId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fld** is a reference to your entity fields (**metadata**), not the entity instance itself.

In SaveHandler, this.**Row** references to created/updated entity with new values, while this.**Old** references entity with old values for update (kinda similar to a SQL trigger).

So you should write `Row.LastModifiedBy = userId;`

FYI, instead of doing it this way in every repository, implement **IUpdateLogRow** (and/or InsertLogRow) interfaces in your entity and default save behaviors will fill Insert/Update UserId/Date fields automatically.

Define a base row like **LoggingRow** sample in Serene to avoid having to implement this interface in every entity.

Comment: I ll try to implement IUpdateLogRow . Thanks